# Ubuntu is showing multiple notification when volume is changed

Tags: 16.04, sound, shortcut-keys, xfce, notification

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with xfce4. When I increase or decrease volume using keyboard shortcuts I am seeing two notifications for the same. How do I fix it?

[image]

You can see the two notification in the right top corner. One has volume icon and other has not.

Comment: sudo apt remove xfce4-notifyd

Comment: I don't want to remove xfce4-notifyd. It will disable other notifications too.

Comment: then unity notify-usd must be running

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I solved this by disabling **xfce-volumed**, Pulseaudio plugin was running along with it.

Open a Terminal window and type `killall xfce4-volumed` and try to change volume now. Only one notification will be shown.

To disable **xfce4-volumed** permanently open **Session and Startup** from settings manager. Go to *Application Autostart* tab. Look for *XFCE Volume Daemon (pulseaudio)* and untick it to disable.

**Edit:**

A more simple approach I found is to right-click on the volume icon in the panel and open properties. Uncheck the 'show notification when volume changes' box and log out/in.

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because of inclusion of Unity related indicator in Xfce. Which is Indicator-Plugin. But if you remove it, you'll lose other indicators with it like messaging etc.

**The Solution**

1. Right click on an empty space of the Panel -> **Panel** -> **Panel Properties**
2. Go to **Items** Tab
3. Select **Indicator Plugin**
4. Click on the right side small wrench icon. Tooltip will say *Edit the currently selected Item*
5. On the new **Indicators** window, There is a list of indicators which are provided by this Indicator Plugin.
6. Place a tick mark for the **Sound Menu** entry. This will be hidden on next panel restart.
7. Close this **Indicators** window.
8. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> to bring Run command dialog box.
9. Type `xfce4-panel -r` and Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

   *Alternatively you can Logout/Login without performing step 8 and 9*

   The panel will be restarted and you'll see the volume icon is gone. Now, we need a volume icon for it.
10. Install `xfce4-pulseaudio-plugin`

    ```
    sudo apt install xfce4-pulseaudio-plugin
    ```
11. Now again right click on the panel -> Panel -> Add New Items and Add **PulseAudio Plugin**
12. Move it to a suitable location in the panel.
13. Change volume and see only one notification (to rule them all!)

Comment: This didn't solve the problem. I tried `killall xfce4-volumed` and now only one notification is being shown.

Comment: you logged out and login again? This will fully works when you do so

Comment: Yes. After logging in no notification was shown when I changed volume. I added **pulseaudio plugin** to the panel and then again I saw two notifications.

Comment: when I kill xfce4-volumed I only see one notification. I removed pulseaudio plugin and and I see only one notification. I think **volumed** and  **pulseaudio-plugin** are showing two seprate notifications.

Comment: i removed **volumed** from startup and restarted. Now the problem is fixed.

Comment: In my system, I solved this way though. Glad to know you solved it. You can make another answer saying that